# Graph Theory: Simple Planar graph problem.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

The complement of $G$ is the graph with the same vertices as $G$, but whose
edges are precisely the non-edges of $G$. (That is, $u$ is adjacent to $v$ in the complement
of $G$ if and only $u$ is not adjacent to $v$ in $G$.) Therefore, if $G^c$
is the complement of $G$,
then $E(K_{|V (G)|}
)$ is the disjoint union of $E(G)$ and $E(G^c
)$.
Show that if $G$ is a simple planar graph with at least eleven vertices, then the complement of $G$ is not planar.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Remember Euler's criterion: if $G$ is a planar graph, then $\epsilon\le 3\nu-6$.